# Adding A Class To <A> Tag

Tags: php

this code  I used to display paginating links... problem is I need to add some style to the links when its active.. I can style it through some CSS rules.. but at first need to add a class to link tag.. Eg:

```
    // Make the links to other pages, if necessary.
    if ($pages > 1) {

        echo '<div class="pagination">';            
            echo '<p>';

            // Determine what page the script is on:
            $current_page = ($start/$display) + 1;

            // If it's not the first page, make a Previous link:
            if ($current_page != 1) {
                echo '<a href="searching.php?s=' . ($start - $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '"><</a>';
            }

            // Make all the numbered pages:
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
                if ($i != $current_page) {
                    echo '<a href="searching.php?s=' . (($display * ($i - 1))) . '&p=' . $pages . '">' . $i . '</a> ';
                } else {
                    echo '<a class="current" href="#">' . $i . '</a> '; // Link to # so that it is not clickable.
                }
            } // End of FOR loop.           

            // If it's not the last page, make a Next button:
            if ($current_page != $pages) {
                echo '<a href="searching.php?s=' . ($start + $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '">></a>';
            }

            echo '</p>'; // Close the paragraph.

        echo '</div>';

    } // End of links section.
```

can anybody have any idea how to do this?

thank you..

Comment: Sorry, what's the problem here? You appear to be in complete control of the markup, so just add the `class` attribute and value(s) to the elements you want

Comment: You don't seem to be showing the link for the active page. Add a link with class where it is now as `echo $i . ' ';`.

Comment: no.. I only need to add a class to <a> tag when page is active.. assume page 1 is active.. then I need to add a class to that link.. resion is I need to style the link when it is activating..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `<a href="` with something like `<a class="current" href="`.

So, you would be effectively needing this CSS, as I **assume** that you will be having a `current` page at a time, plus normal page links, and previous and next buttons:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <a href="#" class="prev">Previous</a>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#" class="current">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
</div>
```

Wrap with a `div` with a class `pagination`, so that you can better style it. Now for the styles, you can use a CSS something like this:

```
.pagination {margin: 5px;} /* Give some margin */
.pagination a {color: #09f; text-decoration: none;} /* Give color, remove underline */
.pagination a:hover {font-weight: bold;} /* Effect when mouse over */
.pagination a.prev, .pagination a.next {color: #06f;} /* Let previous and next be in different color*/
.pagination a.current {color: #000; font-weight: bold;} /* Black and bold! */
```

#### Screenshot:

This would look this way:

[image: Screenshot]

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Z9Jk/

#### To change in your code:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
 if ($i != $current_page) {
  echo '<a href="searching.php?s=' . (($display * ($i - 1))) . '&p=' . $pages . '">' . $i . '</a> ';
 } else {
  echo '<a class="current" href="#">' . $i . '</a> '; // Link to # so that it is not clickable.
 }
}
```

#### Please change these:

1.

```
if ($current_page != 1) {
    echo '<a class="prev" href="searching.php?s=' . ($start - $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '"><</a>';
}
```

2.

```
if ($current_page != $pages) {
    echo '<a class="next" href="searching.php?s=' . ($start + $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '">></a>';
}
```

Comment: I have styled it.. but problem is I cant style when a link is activating... eg: if page 1 is active then I need to add some styles for that link. thats why I need to add another class to the <a>..

Comment: @PriyankaKumara Give a class named `current` when the page is current page. You can check the condition something like this: `<a<?php echo ($current_page == 1) ? ' class="current"' : ""; ?> href="searching.php?"`

Comment: my page number generating through a for loop... assume there is 100 pages then I need to add 100 condition..isnt it?

Comment: No! I said just in the 3 `<a>` tags. Let me update my answer with what you asked.

Comment: @PriyankaKumara Updated, please check.

Comment: thanks.. but styles for current class is not working..

Comment: Did you add the CSS? @PriyankaKumara Can you update the current code in your question?

Comment: yes.. this is my css.. a.current {
 background: #e46700;
 color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
}

Comment: @PriyankaKumara Updated the changes. Please check **Please change these** section.

Comment: then... what I need to do.. still css not working

Comment: @PriyankaKumara Do you have a stylesheet in your application? If so, add those CSS lines there. If not, declare a `<style>` tag in your application's `<head>` section, and put the contents there. Hope it helps. Let me know if you got them right. Do you have a place where we can access it?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `class="whatever"` to the appropriate `echo` statements that generate you `<a>` tags.